# Transforming rows into itemsets in R to use arules

Tags: r, associations, arules, market-basket-analysis

I have the results of survey data in the following format

```
ResponseID  Reason1  Reason2  Reason3 ... 
1           'Event'  'Tour'   'Other'
2           'Tour'   'Other'
3           'Event'  'Program'
```

For each survey respondent they selected the reason for their visit to a park.

I would like to run some association rules on the respondent's answers but I can not figure out how to get the data in the appropriate form

I imagine it would look something like

```
ResponseID  Itemset
1           {'Event','Tour','Other'}
2           {'Tour', 'Other'}
3           {'Event','Program'}
```

but I have not been able to decipher to documentation of ItemMatrix and R is not a language I am very familiar in - thanks!

Comment: you can try - `apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ",")`

Answer (score 0):

Write the dataframe to a file with `write.table` and then used `read.transactions` with `format = "basket"`.